# Slow midnight commander startup

Tags: ubuntu, performance, bashrc, midnight-commander, delayed-execution

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.

I'm midnight commander user. When i starts terminal and then type "mc", it starts immediately. But i don't want to type it every time i open terminal. So i added "mc" to end of .bashrc file. As result, mc is starting, but very slow - it added 3 sec delay.

Solutions like disable subshell aren't good. Hostname is resolving well. What else can i do?

Thanks.

Comment: What I do is to assign `xterm -e mc` to a key combination. How you do that depends on your window manager.

Answer (score 0):

Found this one using google trying to get autorun MC on Ubuntu Server when ssh connected. I found the solution:

Add "mc" into `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`) instead of `~/.bashrc` file. Then it would start normally and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> will work as expected.